# MS Project displaying work hours extremely wrong compared to duration and resource allocation

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

I am having an issue with working hours in my project plan with the work hours showing millions of hours even though when factoring duration and resources this is off by a huge margin.

For Example:

I have a task that has a duration of 66 days (Mon-Fri/ 8 hours per day) with 1 resource allocated and it is populating 13,144 hours when based on working hours it should only equal 528. When reviewing the task usage view, it is showing 199.15 hours per day.

Please help in figuring out how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try removing the resource assignment and re-adding it. Make sure there is only 1 unit assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: The only way we were able to resolve the issue was to take the duration and work columns and copy them into excel. We then had to have excel recalculate the work based on an 8 hour day. Once complete we copy and pasted the columns back into the project